# How to pass props from Formik to the rendered Form?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have the following FormikWrapper which returns a Formik form:

```
const FormikWrapper = (props) => {
  const { name } = props;  
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        email: '',
        password: '',
      }}
      
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, props }) => {
        console.log('submitted', values);

      }}
    >
      {({ submitForm, isSubmitting, name }) => (
        <Form>
            <p>Form name is :{name}</p>
          <Field
            component={TextField}
            name="email"
            type="email"
            label="Email"
          />
          <br />
          <Field
            component={TextField}
            type="password"
            label="Password"
            name="password"
          />
          <Button
            onClick={submitForm}
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}

export default FormikWrapper
```

I want to set the form's name by passing it to the `FormikWrapper`'s props.
How do I pass it down from `<Formik>` into the rendered form template (so that the `Form name is: {name}` is filled) ?

Comment: Aren't your code already doing what you want?

Comment: No,  the name props is undefined.. if I change the way I write Formik to use  ```<Formik children={props=> <SomeForm {...props} name={name}  />} />``` then it works.

Comment: Aren't you getting the name here `const { name } = props;` ?

Comment: I do get it there, but it doesn't seem to pass from the FormikWrapper, through Formik, to the actual rendered form (in ```Form name is : {name}```
If I change my code so that I define ```<Formik children=...>``` as in my previous comment then it works..

Comment: Could please show where and how you use the component `FormikWrapper` ?

Comment: Oh I found it.. the ```name``` prop was specifically mentioned in the props I passed from Formik. That's why it was undefined. (sorry it was missing in the example I pasted, I changed the code to get it to work a few times. I updated my example to the code that failed). Erasing 'name' in the ```{({ submitForm, isSubmitting, name }) => (``` section fixes it.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.
The problem was I passed the `name` var with the other vars

```
  {({ submitForm, isSubmitting, name }) => (
     <Form>
            <p>Form name is :{name}</p>
```

and so it became undefined.

Once I removed it from there then the `name` var from the wrapper scope was used.